# Choosing a web framework for a 3rd party twitter app

Tags: django, postgresql, mongodb, tornado

I'm building an application to provide a RESTful web service using the twitter API(Search and REST), my current stack is django+postgresql. I have some processes continually collecting new information from twitter  so the db is always growing. I'm not sure if django and postgresql are a good choice for this kind of application.

The application is currently running slowly(e.g. one view makes 682 queries to show the results, another one 2228) so I'm considering trying to improve the performance tweaking the queries, cacheing all I can and running some tasks asinchronically or directly making a switch to Tornado with mongodb(through asyncmongo).

Comment: 682? 2228? Wow. Are you doing all of your query logic in Python rather than SQL perhaps?

Comment: If you are making thousands of queries for a single view, chances are that the problem lies in the application architecture more than the choice of implementation tools. Are those per-view queries to Twitter or your database (either would be problematic)?  I'm guessing these are database queries since the Twitter API has much lower [rate limits](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting).  It sounds like you should be looking for a more efficient approach such as paginating your views or writing SQL that joins data in result set(s) with fewer queries.

Comment: Yes, I know there's something wrong with the application architecture or at least for the way the queries are made. I'll try to optimize the app following this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/optimization/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should understand that tornado will downgrade your application on heavy views. Django is better for apps with thousands of queries on page, cause chaos will be less with blocking model in this case.

Second, yes, switching to tornado + mongodb can improve your application, because you will have to rethink your storage architecture.

Problem here is in storage, not in tools. Try to find how to reduce queries in views, maybe by making heavier calculations in background.